# Can't get hidden menu to expand, even though the same code words elsewhere .

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm working on my navigation bar, and when I first started working on it, I figured out the display: none / display: blocked thing to make sure it worked, and then set everything to display so I could see what CSS changes were taking effect without having to go and re-hover over everything. Once I had things the way I wanted them, I went to go turn the display "off" but found it suddenly wasn't working. I managed to go back and re-tweak most of the levels, but my last level wont work, even though the same basic syntax works elsewhere in my CSS. What's going on?

Here's a JSfiddle:

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/yu1p1fo6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two classes were incorrectly named drop-down instead of drop-menu

Comment: THANK YOU! Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong class name in that part. It is not drop-down, it is drop-menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/yu1p1fo6/2/

```
.sub-menu li .drop-menu {
    display: none;
}

.sub-menu li:hover .drop-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! (smack-head) such a simple oversight.